# Problem with the render of a value from my api

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to render the maxoffer that i get from my api, but when i try to render the value it says undefined, how can i render it on the first try?

this is my code

```
const [vPayrollBureauMaxOffer, setvPayrollBureauMaxOffer] = useState();
const [vPayrollAmount, setvPayrollAmount] = useState(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer);

useEffect(() => {
  let isUnmount = false
  async function Request() {
    const {data} = await ForceApi.post(`/someapi.php`);
    setvPayrollBureauMaxOffer(data.vPayrollBureauMaxOffer);
  }
  Request();
  return () => {
    setisLoading(false);
    isUnmount = true
  }
}, []);

return (
 <View style={styles.inputContainer2}>
   <Text style={styles.inputs2}>$</Text>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputs}
      placeholder={`${vPayrollAmount}`}
      placeholderTextColor={theme.SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR}
      keyboardType={'numeric'}
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="characters"
      value= {`${vPayrollAmount}`}
      onChangeText={setvPayrollAmount}
      />
     </View>
   );
```

Comment: console.log the data you are getting from the api

Comment: im sure it return a value in this case  "vPayrollBureauMaxOffer": "200000.00"

Comment: Ok. So from your code it seems like you want update `setvPayrollAmount` through `setvPayrollBureauMaxOffer` after making the api call. Are you trying to update `vPayrollAmount` using this methods? Why not just update it directly? Is `vPayrollAmount` what is returning the undefined?

Comment: yea, im trying to update vPayrollAmount, i dont do it directly because im doing another calculations whit this value. and the  vPayrollAmount  value is going to change, im going to put  a counter to modify the value later, but i need to render that value first. and yes it seems it is vPayrollAmount  the one returning undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I noticed a few things in your code.
The first thing is that you dont have value set for your first initial state so I would set it as an empty string
Secondly your `vPayrollAmount` value doesnt automically update with change in `vPayrollBureauMaxOffer` so there is no point setting it the way you are right now. Just make it empty

```
const [vPayrollBureauMaxOffer, setvPayrollBureauMaxOffer] = useState('');
const [vPayrollAmount, setvPayrollAmount] = useState('');
```

Next you should set another useEffect that listens to change in the `vPayrollBureauMaxOffer` value to update the `vPayrollAmount`

```
useEffect(() => {
  setvPayrollAmount(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer)
}, [vPayrollBureauMaxOffer]);
```

Comment: genius, it was so logic that i feel dumb, thanks for your time